# parse Xml on HTML5 windows phone application

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

i'm looking for an example to parse xml feed in windows phone application using HTML5 Views.

Answer (score 0):

Gothrough this

http://blog.jayway.com/2011/11/07/wp7-getting-started-5-using-databound-controls-to-display-an-rss-feed/

Comment: thanks man but i was talking about integrating HTML5...not a simple databound in windows phone !